# Text inside div moves right or left when resize window

Tags: html, css

The webpage is this: http://www.peliculadicto.tk/
Every time i resize my window, the text inside the color grey bar with position: fixed at the upper, moves to sides. It never stays centered. How can i prevent this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="headbar">
    <h1 id="logo">
        <a href="url" title="Ver peliculas de terror, de miedo, infantiles">Películas buenas</a>
    </h1>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="url">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="url" class="drop">Peliculas</a></li>   
            <li><a href="url" class="drop">Estrenos</a></li>            
            <li><a href="url">Ranking</a></li><li><a href="url">Proximamente</a></li>
            <li><a href="url">Más vistas</a></li>
        </ul>

        (search) <div id="uwpqsf_idsr"><form id="uwpqsffrom_641" method="get" action="url"><div class="uform_titlesr"></div><input type="hidden" name="unonce" value="4b52cced4e"><input type="hidden" name="uformid" value="641"><input type="hidden" name="s" value="uwpsfsearchtrg"><div class="uwpqsf_classsr"><input id="uwpqsf_id_keysr" type="text" name="skeyword" class="uwpqsftext" placeholder="Busca por título, actor, director, género..." value=""></div></form></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.uwpqsf_classsr { 
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2.5px;
    left: 57px; 
}

.headbar {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 42px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #9B9595;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#B6AAAA,#000000);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0,0% 100%,from(#B6AAAA),to(#000000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(177, 185, 185),rgb(73, 68, 73));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#B6AAAA,#000000);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A29A9A;
    z-index: 3000;
    opacity: 0.65;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 700px;
    left: 221px;
}

#menu>ul>li { 
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:27px;
    left:370px;
}
```

Comment: `i resize window the text inside it moves to right or left.` It stays fixed for me. What do you want it to do?

Comment: Yes, it stays fixed but the text inside of it goes right or left; the div that has this text moves inside this fixed bar. I want to prevent that.

Comment: The text stays still for me. Again, you need to be clearer about what you want.

Comment: Well, that's weird, for me it does not stay still. It goes to sides at resizing window. Never stays centered. Can't go trough it yet with the current answers, can't catch up.

Comment: The text is stays fixed and it won't move on window resizing. It might be your browser issue. can you specify which version of browser you are using or having this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, maybe i didn't explain myself.
However, i've already fixed, took a very large time to figure out. Time for me and anyone who wants to compare:

**CSS**

```
.headbar {
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 42px;
margin: 0px auto;
background-color: #9B9595;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#B6AAAA,#000000);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0,0% 100%,from(#B6AAAA),to(#000000));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(177, 185, 185),rgb(73, 68, 73));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#B6AAAA,#000000);
border-bottom: 1px solid #A29A9A;
z-index: 3000;
opacity: 0.65;
}

#menu {
margin: 0px 332px 0px auto;
width: 48%;
position: relative;
right: 178px;
}

#menu>ul>li {
float:left;
height:27px;
margin-top:13px;
}

.uwpqsf_classsr { 
}

input#uwpqsf_id_keysr {
color: #FFFFFF; 
width:277px;
height:30px; 
padding-left: 32px;
background: rgba(56, 53, 53, 0.12) url(/lupa.png) no-repeat; 
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="headbar">
                <h1 id="logo">
                    <a href="http://www.peliculadicto.tk" title="Ver peliculas de terror, de miedo, infantiles">Películas buenas</a>
                </h1>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.peliculadicto.tk">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.peliculadicto.tk/tag/peliculas" class="drop">Peliculas</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.peliculadicto.tk/tag/estrenos" class="drop">Estrenos</a></li>           
<li><a href="http://www.peliculadicto.tk/ranking">Ranking</a></li><li><a href="http://www.peliculadicto.tk/archivos/proximamente">Proximamente</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.peliculadicto.tk/tag/peliculas/?v_sortby=views&amp;v_orderby=desc">Más vistas</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="uwpqsf_idsr"><form id="uwpqsffrom_641" method="get" action="http://www.peliculadicto.tk/"><div class="uform_titlesr"></div><input type="hidden" name="unonce" value="4b52cced4e"><input type="hidden" name="uformid" value="641"><input type="hidden" name="s" value="uwpsfsearchtrg"><div class="uwpqsf_classsr"><input id="uwpqsf_id_keysr" type="text" name="skeyword" class="uwpqsftext" placeholder="Busca por título, actor, director, género..." value=""></div></form></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the

```
#menu {
  left: 221px;
}
```

that's doing it.

Answer (score 0):

this is happened because of `left:221px` in a `#menu`. you can use a `float:right` for to fix  a div at right side.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the left is set to fixed px. When the Window resizes, the space looks larger but in fact the space stays the same and it's the window that becomes smaller. Try using percent.